# Is it true that any set which contains elements with contradictory properties is the empty set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, solution-verification

Here's what I've "discovered" but can't verify.

Let's take a set $A$ defined as "the set of all $x$ which don't belong to $A$".

Obviously this definition wouldn't hold in particular axiomatic systems, but it would in others.

Let's analyze this in NST. $X\in A$ iff $X\not\in A$.

This is a logical contradiction, but it still doesn't prove that $A$ doesn't exist. In fact, I would argue that $A$ is the empty set.

If put all of the elements of $A$ into the empty set, we get $(X∈A \text { iff } X∉A) \text { iff } X\in \emptyset$.

This is a tautology for whatever $X$ and $A$. Now, if we switch two of the atomic sentences, we get $X\not\in A \text { iff } (X\in A \text { iff } X\in\emptyset$). We know this to also always be true, which means that either $A$ doesn't exist or $A$ is the empty set.

Therefore, the empty set does contain every element belonging to any set it doesn't belong to.

Is there some error in my proof?

Comment: $\forall x\colon(x\in a\leftrightarrow \neg(x\in a))$ is a contradcition. Hence no object $a$ of our domain of discourse (i.e. no set $a$) exists with the property $\forall x\colon(x\in a\leftrightarrow \neg(x\in a))$. Heck, already $\exists x\colon(x\in a\leftrightarrow \neg(x\in a))$ would be contradictory. Perhaps what you confuse with emptyness is that the domain of discoourse mght be empty (i.e., no set exists at all) - but then of course also no set $a$ exists.

Comment: $(p\iff q)\iff r$ is not equivalent to $p\iff(q\iff r)$.

Comment: Ulrich, could you give me a truth value set for p, q, and r, such that the equivalence doesn't hold? As I see it, if all three are true, then both equivalences are always true, if just one of p,q, or r si false, then both of the equivalences are always false, if two are false, then the equivalences are always true, and if all three are false, then both of the equivalences are false. Am I missing something?

Comment: I would say it isn't a definition at all in that it requires itself in the definition.  That'd be like defining Sam as the person who lives at Sam's address.

Answer (score 3):

The statement $$(*)\quad(X∈A \text { iff } X∉A) \text { iff } X\in \emptyset$$ does not mean what you seem to think it means (though I'm not sure exactly what you think it means).  If $A=\{X:X\not\in A\}$, then $(X∈A \text { iff } X∉A)$ must be true *for all* $X$.  When you assert $(*)$ you are asserting that $(X∈A \text { iff } X∉A)$ is true if $X\in\emptyset$, but also that it is false if $X\not\in\emptyset$.  So if $A$ actually is equal to $\{X:X\not\in A\}$, then this statement (with an implicit universal quantifier on $X$) is *false*, since $(X∈A \text { iff } X∉A)$ would be true for all $X$, even $X$ such that $X\not\in\emptyset$.

Again, I'm not entirely sure what your train of thought is, but it sounds like you are confusing $$A=\{X:X\not\in A\}$$ with $$A=\{X:X∈A \text { iff } X∉A\}.$$  If $A$ was supposed to satisfy the latter equation, then $A=\emptyset$ would be equivalent to $(*)$ (and indeed, your argument then correctly shows that $A=\emptyset$ satisfies the latter equation).  But the first equation is quite different.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $A$ is a set such that $x\in A$ if and only if $x\notin A$.
Now it's certainly true that from $x\in A$ we can deduce $x\in\varnothing$.
Also, vacuously, from $x\in\varnothing$ we can deduce $x\in A$.

This does not mean $A$ exists and is $\varnothing$. All we have deduced is that *if* $A$ exists *then* it must be $\varnothing$. But going back and substituting $A=\varnothing$ doesn't work: taking $x=\varnothing$ too we have $\varnothing\notin\varnothing$, which should imply $\varnothing\in\varnothing$, but the latter is false. The only explanation is that our original assumption - that such an $A$ exists - was wrong.

This is analogous to the following argument.
Suppose there is a real number $x$ such that $x^2+x+1=0$. Multiplying both sides by $x-1$, we get $x^3-1=0$, i.e. $x^3=1$, and the only real number satisfying this is $x=1$.

What we have just done is to deduce that *if* such a real number exists *then* it must be $1$ - but it doesn't, so it isn't.

Answer (score -1):

NO. If we assume $\exists x: [x\in A \land [P(x) \land \neg P(x)]]$ we can easily obtain a contradiction. Therefore, such a set $A$ cannot exist.

**EDIT:** In your example, if we assume $\exists x: [x\in A \land [x\in A \iff x \notin A]]$ we can similary obtain a contradiction. Therefore, in this case, too, such a set $A$ cannot exist.

BTW, when you say that a set contains any elements, you rule out that it is empty.

**EDIT:** Also, if you assume $x\in A \iff x\notin A$, this is already a contradiction. We can only conclude that there cannot exist such a set $A$ and element/object $x$.

We can, however, define an empty set $E$ given set A as follows:

$\forall x: [x \in E \iff x \in A \land x \notin A]$